# watch and apply changes to object in angular js service

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-rootscope

i am trying to change and apply the value of an object in an angular js service.

i have been able to successfully watch the object and i saw the changes but i cannot apply it to take effect .

i am changing the value from my login controller .

i am watching the $rootScope.userobject and would want to apply changes immediately to $rootScope.userobj as it used in my service for some important stuff but it doesn't seem to apply . what am i doing wrong . see my code below

```
            MyApp.angular.factory('appService', function ($rootScope, $timeout) {

              $rootScope.userobject = localStorage.getItem('userdataconfig');
              $rootScope.userobj = JSON.parse($rootScope.userobject);

              if(!rootScope.userobj){
              $rootScope.userobj = {};
              }

              $rootScope.$watchCollection('userobject', function(newvalue, oldvalue)
            {
              $timeout(function(){

               $rootScope.userobject = newvalue;
               $rootScope.userobj = JSON.parse($rootScope.userobject);// i need this updated value to take effect so i can use it in my userconfig below

             });
            }, true);



            return {
                    userconfig: {token: $rootScope.userobj.token, id: $rootScope.userobj.id, username: "josieboy", fullname: $rootScope.userobj.name, profile_pix: ""}
                }

            })

            MyApp.angular.controller('loginctrl', ['appService', '$scope', '$http', 'InitService', '$rootScope', function (appService, $scope, $http, InitService, $rootScope) {
            $scope.loginnow = function()
            {
              var userdata = { 'id': 3, 'token':'867eb6fcd04b543f97ff6d2c0a64c557', 'name':'Ajose Joshua', 'profile_pix':''};
              localStorage.setItem('userdataconfig', JSON.stringify(userdata));
              var userobject = localStorage.getItem('userdataconfig');
              $rootScope.userobject = userdata;

              }

            }])
```

Comment: you inject `appService` to your controller but you don't use it.

Comment: @JoeLloyd i am actually using it for something else .. i didn't want to put up the full long code here.

Comment: you save in `userconfig` reference to _token_ field, and when update _$rootScope.userobj_ this not affect saved value, because you just change reference